# Handling Rails multi language websites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

When using Rails to build a complex content website, what is the easiest way to *cleanly* handle multi language support?

We're looking at localizing an existing website in 10+ languages and would like to find the easiest way to handle significant amounts of multi language content.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Comment: from experience I can advise you to be aware that internationalization adds significant amount of resistance to the development speed. It helps to pull commonly-used words ('submit', 'cancel', etc) into a shared hierarchy, vs being associated with a particular page or model.

Comment: Storyblok CMS with Rails if affordable :))